# Меню не исчезает при скролле

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

У меня проблема, когда я скроллю страницу меню не исчезает/появляется вот код

```js
var headero = $('#header').offset();
var header = $('#header');
window.onscroll = function(){
 if (headero.top >= 10) {
 header.hide();
 }
}
```

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 height:10000px;
 
}
#header {
width:100%;
float:left;
height:50px;
background:#fafafa;
box-shadow:0 0 3px #ccc;
position:fixed;
line-height:50px;
padding-left:20px;
font-family:sans-serif;
color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">Home</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что вы один раз .offset() посчитали, а потом крути не крути - сравниваете с начальным значением.

```js
var header = $('#header');
window.onscroll = function(){
 if (header.offset().top >= 10) {
     header.hide();
 }else{
     header.show();
    }
}
```

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 height:10000px;
 
}
#header {
width:100%;
float:left;
height:50px;
background:#fafafa;
box-shadow:0 0 3px #ccc;
position:fixed;
line-height:50px;
padding-left:20px;
font-family:sans-serif;
color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">Home</div>
```